# Wordpress redirect if URL parameter is empty for each post

Tags: wordpress, redirect

So there are people who access my website directly (not thru the tracking link I got with Voluum), thus they are not able to click the links and I can't see them as a part of my stats.
How can I redirect users who don't have a `/?voluumdata=BASE64...` URL parameter to a tracked URL, and to have a different redirect for each blog post?

I was testing and looking for a plugin / .htaccess trick for hours but nothing seemed to help.

Edit: I found a solution that I was certain is going to work but for some reason it didn't:

```
[insert_php]

if(empty($_GET['voluumdata'])) 
{ 
  header('Location: REDIRECT_URL');
  exit; 
}
[/insert_php]
```

Also tried:

```
[insert_php]
if(!isset($_GET['voluumdata'])) 
{ 
  header('Location: REDIRECT_URL');
  exit; 
}
[/insert_php]
```

Both just break the page loading proccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot understand what is the purpose of the code you have entered in your question. I mean that is not clear the reason you use the tags `[insert_php]`.

A solution to your problem it can be the following.

```
function redirect_direct_access( ) {
    // You may use the code:
    //
    //     global $wp_query
    //
    // in order to determine in which pages you should run your
    // redirection code. If you only check for the token existence
    // then you will be faced with redirection loop. I don't explain in
    // depth how to use the $wp_query as it is not part of your question
    // but you always have the opportunity to check what is the contents
    // of this variable using the code:
    //
    //    echo "<pre>";
    //    print_r( $wp_query );
    //    echo "</pre>";
    //
    // This way you will be able to build your specific if statement
    // for the page you like to test.

    if ( 
        ! isset( $_GET[ 'voluumdata' ] ) ||
        empty( $_GET[ 'voluumdata' ] ) 
    ) { 
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/page/to/redirect/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_direct_access' );
```

You can find more information in the WordPress documentation related to the [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook.

Comment: That sounds good, but what If I need to set a different redirect URL per post? The purpose is that tracking services like Voluum are only tracking visitors via unique link they give you, they don't have an option to track visitors with a js script like Google Analytics. The `[insert_php]` tags are tags that are used with a WP plugin that let's you inject php code directly into the post.

Comment: So after a small research I've almost did it, the only problem I'm having now is with the pages detection. So let's say I want to create an `IF` for a post ID 180, would I add `is_page( 180 ) &&` before the `!isset`? for some reason it doesn't work and fires the redirect on all the pages. Any help?

Comment: Then your solution with the `[insert_php]` shortcode cannot work, as you should do any redirection in PHP before you print any character to the browser. That's why you cannot do any redirection. Now if you try to use the code I have in comments in the above snippet, you will find that is possible to have the ID of the page and/or the post the visitor accessing. Just try this code `global $wp_query; echo "<pre>"; print_r( $wp_query ); echo "</pre>";` and you will find too much information for the given page you visit. Hope this helps you. Finally, if you are happy with my answer, please up vote

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone would face the same issue, @Merianos Nikos has given a half-answer and I mastered it into this:

```
function redirect_direct_access( ) {

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( 
    $post_id == POST_ID &&
        !isset( $_GET[ 'voluumdata' ] )
    ) { 
        wp_redirect( 'REDIRECT_URL' );
        exit();
    }

    if ( 
    $post_id == POST_ID &&
        !isset( $_GET[ 'voluumdata' ] )
    ) { 
        wp_redirect( 'REDIRECT_URL' );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_direct_access' );
```